# Script import errors while in another folder to main script

Tags: python, import, directory

I have a script (script 1) that imports another script (script 2) which is in a folder with the same directory as script 1. This is fine as I added `import [folder].[script 2]`
However script 2 imports another script (script 3) which is in the same folder as script 2 but when I run script 1 script 2 can't find script 3.

I hope you can follow this haha, and I should mention that neither script 2 or script 3 can be edited due to it being a copy of the actual scripts that will be used when the program is implemented.

Is there any way of telling script 2 to look in that folder?

Edit: I realise a similar question has been posted before, however in my case it's important to remember I cannot edit script 2 or 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code to mimic the situation you described:

```
# subfolder/script3.py
def f3():
    print("Hello")
```

```
# subfolder/script2.py
from script3 import f3
def f2():
    f3()
```

```
# script1_v1.py
from script2 import f2
f2()
## -> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'script2'

# script1_v2.py
from subfolder.script2 import f2
f2()
## -> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'script3'
```

The easiest solution is to add the path to the scripts into `sys.path`:

```
# script1_v3.py
import sys
sys.path.append("subfolder")

from sc2 import f2
f2()
```

This solution is not really clean because depending on the name of your scripts, it might interfere with python standard libraries, e.g. if they are called something like `sys.py` or `os.py`.

Other solutions exist but you will need to provide more information like where do script 2 and 3 come from and why can't you modify them.

EDIT:

For the sake of completeness, there is another solution that may work for you and is cleaner, but requires to slightly modify `script2.py`:

```
# subfolder/script2.py
from .script3 import f3
def f2():
    f3()
```

Notice the dot in the import line. It should not impact the interaction between other modules (unless they did some shady stuffs) and the version with `subfolder.script2` should now work normally without modifying `sys.path`.

Comment: Yep, this did it thanks man. I'm working on a script for a company who have provided me the other two scripts as libraries for what I need to do. However other unrelated scripts also rely on these libraries so changing them would break things I don't even know exist right now